# Angular material MatTableDataSource Serverside pagination not working

Tags: datatable, pagination, angular-material, observable

I am new to angular, I am trying to apply material table with pagination and sorting. So, Initially I try with pagination. I stuck with this error. Do anyone help me out with pagination.

the error is:

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() =>
>   Observable'.

***servertable.component.ts***

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { IUser } from './model/IUser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-servertable',
  templateUrl: './servertable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./servertable.component.scss']
})
export class ServertableComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit {

  dataSource: any;
  users: IUser[];
  displayedColumns = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'company'];      

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private service: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getUser.subscribe(results => this.users = results);
    console.dir(this.dataSource);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}
```

***user.service.ts***

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { IUser } from './model/IUser';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private serviceUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUser(): Observable<IUser[]> {
    return this.http.get<IUser[]>(this.serviceUrl);
  }
}
```

***servertable.component.html***

```html
<div>
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> E-Mail </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.email}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Phone </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.phone}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Company </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.company.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling your service method: `this.service.getUser.subscribe(results => this.users = results);`. You've forgotten to add parentheses on `getUser`.

Change it to: `this.service.getUser().subscribe(results => this.users = results);`

There is one more problem: `this.users` will not yet be available in `ngAfterContentInit` because the `getUser()` call is asynchronous. Move the assignment of the table to your `subscribe()` call. The whole `ngOnInit()` will look like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getUser().subscribe(results => {
        this.users = results;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
}
```

Comment: Tq Tim, Could you help me to add sorting for these fields.

Comment: @chandoo it's not that hard, but maybe too long to put in a comment: 1: add `MatSortModule` to your module. 2: servertable.component.ts: add `@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;` and assign it in onInit: `this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;`. 3: your html: add `matSort` to `mat-table`: `<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>` and add `mat-sort-header` to every `mat-header-cell` eg `<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>`. That should do the trick. If not working please post another question

Comment: Hi, tq for the code treat. It helped me to complete the sorting as well. Thanks a lot @Tim.